# Multi-Core Subprocess Execution in Python

Tags: python, c, parallel-processing, subprocess, multiprocessing

I would like to run a model , which is written in c, several times by calling it in python script. During this multiple executions, I want to use multiple cores therefore decrease execution time as much as possible.

So far I found out that subprocess and multiprocess libraries to help my problem. However, the model uses same input folder to get input files but producing output files in different folder. All these paths are specified in scenario file which is specified as an argument in the execution of model. I will collect the outputs later therefore having them in separate output folders is preferable for me. However, I wonder if it is possible to manage this shared input situation in python without interfering the c code.

```
import multiprocessing                               
import subprocess                                      
from subprocess import call
from time import strftime, localtime


def run_model(num,par_arr,scenarioPath):

    cmd =["./model","model_model",str(scenarioPath),str(par_arr[0]), str(par_arr[1]),str(par_arr[2]), str(par_arr[3]),str(par_arr[4]),str(par_arr[5])]
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)

    return

if __name__ == '__main__' :
jobs =[]
start = time.time()

print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S \n", localtime())
path = os.getcwd()

scenarioPath = str(path) 
#just to demonstrate two sets of run                                                         
parameterArray = [[20, 100 ,0.13,100,55,55],[30, 100 ,0.13,100,55,55]]

for i in range(0,len(parameterArray)):

   p = multiprocessing.Process(target = run_model,args=((i+1),parameterArray[i],scenarioPath))
   jobs.append(p)
   p.start()


  end = time.time()

  print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S \n", localtime())
  print("Elapsed time in seconds: " +str(end-start))
```

And last, the elapsed time is written before the model executions finish. Therefore, I am not being able to measure the elapsed time yet with this structure.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Edit: To answer one of the comments below, I rephrase the question again. 
My first question is if it is possible to manage same input reading of the 
subprocess model within python. Although there is a set of parameters
given as input parameters in the python script ( parameterArray), there is a set of other input , as raster files, model reads during its execution. When I try to call the model in python, in parallel , all the calls would like to read the same raster files at the same time.
Namely, model reads input rasters from a folder and this step is same for each run.

My second problem is I cannot get the correct elapsed time with this script above. The script runs the model twice in parallel as expected however it prints the "Elapsed time in seconds: " print statement is written way before the model executions finishes.

Comment: My first question is if it is possible to manage shared input of the subprocess model within python. Model reads input rasters from a folder and this step is same for each run. My second problem is I cannot get the correct elapsed time with this script above. The script runs the model twice in parallel as expected however it prints the `"Elapsed time in seconds: "` print statement is written way before the model executions finishes. What you suggest is to implement with just `subprocess.Popen` ? Does it solely enough to run parallel?